# Greens Theorem Example

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone show me how to computer this integration both ways?

Let $S$ be the annulus $1\leq x^{2} + y^{2} \leq4$. Compute $I=\int_{ \partial S} (xy^{2}\,dy - x^{2}y\,dx)$.

$I=\iint_S (y^{2}\,dA + x^{2}\,dA)=\iint_S (y^{2} + x^{2})\,dA=\int^{4}_{1}(3 y^{2} + 15/3)=(15 + 15)=30$.

In polar the conventional way i get $I=\int^{2 \pi}_{0} \int^{4}_{1} r^{3}\,dr\,d\theta=127.5\pi$.

30 doesn't equal $127.5\pi$ so clearly one of these is wrong im going with the one above.

Comment: By both ways, do you mean you also have to compute the line integral around the boundary as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the annulus $1^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2^2$ and $\partial S$ its positively oriented boundary. As you already noted, we can use Green's theorem to obtain

$$I = \int_{\partial S} (xy^2\,dy - x^2y\,dx) = \iint_S (y^2 + x^2)\,dx\,dy$$

The simplest way to compute this surface integral is to use polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$; however, note that the outer radius is $\sqrt{4}=2$.

$$I = \iint_S r^2 \cdot r\,dr\,d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_1^2 r^3\,dr = 2\pi\left(\frac{2^4}{4} - \frac{1^4}{4}\right) = \frac{15\pi}{2}$$

While it is possible to directly integrate with respect to $x$ and $y$, in this case it will be an unnecessarily messy experience. Note that the limits of integration of $x$ and $y$ depend on the other variable, so your first method cannot be used. The integral to compute here would be

$$I = \int_{x=-2}^{2} \left(\int_{y=-\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{\max(0,1^2-x^2)}} + \int_{y=\sqrt{\max(0,1^2-x^2)}}^{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}\right) (y^2 + x^2)\,dx\,dy$$

As you see, it is preferable to do circularly symmetric integrals in polar coordinates.

Comment: i actually did figure this out before my exam yesterday just didn't have time to post it =) best of all it was on the exam =)